# Is there a way to loop this code but where each time a variable is given a different string?

Tags: c#

So I have some code , works absolutely fine but for only one instance , I want to make it so it will feed itself the next set of variables until there is a set of variables that doesn't exist … it will make sense when you see the code.  The code simply locates and tells the character position and snippets it out of the original text.

So I have tried looping it , that's kinda easy but I don't know  how to change the instance each time

```
//For comparison text
string ImpureCText = "I was very <title> proud of my  my my nickname throughout high school. but today I couldn’t be .any ¡ different to what my </title> nickname was kdrlfmb ksd.f gaeks fak<p1> helllo this is a pharagraph that has been been compressed down by irrelvant words and put into a list so i can compare how many times it pops up up up in the article or in tho</p1>.";// insert text file here
string parastart = "<p1>";  // need to make this so it can change to <p2>. <p3>..etc:
bool b = ImpureCText.Contains(parastart);
string paraend = "</p1>";       // need to make this so it can change to </p2>, </p3>..etc:
bool l = ImpureCText.Contains(paraend);
if (b && l)
{                                                                                                               
    int index1 = ImpureCText.IndexOf(parastart);
    int index2 = ImpureCText.IndexOf(paraend);
    if (index1 >= 0)                                                                                //locates char position of start of pharagraph
        Console.WriteLine("'{0} begins at character position {1}", parastart, index1 + 1 );
    Console.WriteLine("'{0} begins at character position {1}", paraend, index2 + 1);

    //string PurePCText = ImpureCText.Substring(index1, index2);

    string PurePCText = ImpureCText.Substring(index2-index1);
    Console.WriteLine("Over here--"+ PurePCText);
```

so it would basically loop this code through , , ,...  until  is recognised to not exist

Comment: Can you show us the loop you wrote?

Comment: it was literally just a do while loop but I delete it now ;( cant get it  back because I did it a few days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array containing the start and end tags you want to print:

```
var startTags = new[] { "<p1>", "<p2>", ... };
var endTags = new[] { "</p1>", "<p2>", ... };

for (var i = 0; i < startTags.Length; i++)
{
    var startTag = startTags[i];
    var endTag = endTags[i];

    // Do tag stuff
}
```

But if you have an index anyway, you can use that to build the tag strings in the loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    var startTag = $"<p{i}>";
    var endTag = $"</p{i}/>";

    // Do tag stuff
}
```